# I can not install gazebo by cmd "sudo apt-get install ROS-jade-simulator-gazebo"

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the terminal  response me "could not fine ROS-jade-simulator-gazebo pkg"

pls help me! Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236141/i-can-not-install-gazebo-by-cmd-%22sudo-apt-get-install-ros-jade-simulator-gazebo%22/) by [godishair](https://answers.ros.org/users/27079/godishair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Your problem is that the package you want to install does not exist.
Try to write:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-gazebo-*
```

I hope this will help you,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [godishair](https://answers.ros.org/users/27079/godishair/) on 2016-06-16**:
thanks so much!